# Information about how to use YUI to develop an interface for a Java Web Application

Tags: java, user-interface, yui

Can anyone recommend some good sources of information on developing a user interface for a Java Web Application using [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui)
Should I take it as a bad sign that there is scant information about this combination on web?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason that you aren't finding too much is that YUI is a javascript library, not a view layer for an MVC application.  It will help you do a lot of things you want to do on the front end, but is not itself a front end.

Essentially, I would suggest you decide what technology you want to use for your view layer templates in your Java Web Application (JSP, JSF, etc) - then simply integrate YUI as needed into your templates to achieve the desired effects.

The important overall point is that your choice to use YUI is totally unrelated to what technologies you decide to use to build your web application (so my answer would be the same if you said it was a webapp in a different language) as YUI purely works on the client side at the browser level (javascript, css, DOM)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I take it as a bad sign that
>   there is scant information about this
>   combination on web?

No.  What is wrong with the ample and excellent documentation already provided on the YUI site?

If you're looking to build pure JavaScript user interfaces, I would also recommend [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/).  We have built several applications with it and our customers love the look.  It is really easy to pick up thanks to the design of the API, the provided documentation, the numerous samples and the helpful community forums..

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Fybit's product?

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/02/02/fybit-riatrax4js/

-Eric